# How can I subtract the same values from two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the same columns, but one table have more and different values than the other. How can I subtract the same values in two tables.

```
Table 1                Table 2
    Name   Number             Name  Number
    Dan    5                  Dan   2
    Jon    3                  Dev   1
    Dev    2
    Gin    2
```

How can I query to have the result:

```
    Name   Number            
    Dan    3                    
    Jon    3                    
    Dev    1
    Gin    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT table1.name, 
        table1.num-IFNULL(table2.num,0)
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.name=table2.name;
```

`IFNULL()` is to replace `NULL` values with zero(0); returned from table on the right side of the `LEFT JOIN` (`table2`) due to non-existing values.

Read more about [MySQL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).